# Why doesn't a grandchild class's parent handle the initialization of the grandparent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, exception, virtual-inheritance

I did search and couldn't find the issue I'm experiencing, but perhaps I just don't know how to articulate the question clearly.

First, I only have a C++98 compiler on the platform in question, so if you could please keep that in mind when responding, I would appreciate it.

Let me give my example and the error message I'm getting:

```
namespace mal {

struct Exception : virtual std::runtime_error {
  Exception(): std::runtime_error("mal exception") {}
  explicit Exception(const char* msg): std::runtime_error(std::string(msg?msg:"")) {}
  explicit Exception(const std::string& msg): std::runtime_error(msg) {}
  virtual ~Exception() throw() {}
}; // Exception struct

struct OpenException : virtual Exception {
  OpenException(): Exception("mal open error") {}
}; // OpenException struct

}; // mal namespace
```

I get the following error:

```
malt.cpp: In constructor ‘mal::OpenException::OpenException()’:
malt.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::runtime_error::runtime_error()’
```

OpenException inherits Exception, which inherits std::runtime_error and initializes it to a string.  Why doesn't the OpenException initialization statement `Exception("mal open error")` initialize std::runtime_error using the const char* overload of Exception?  Does this not propagate up through the inheritance hierarchy?

If C inherits B and B inherits A, it seems counter to OO principles that C would have to know about the implementation details of A.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104855/inheritance-wrong-call-of-constructors.

Comment: @RSahu Okay, thanks.  My question really had nothing to do with multiple inheritance so I hope you'll leave my "duplicate" out here in case someone has the same problem I did.  My problem was *caused* by virtual inheritance; however, without knowing that, I wasn't going to formulate a good search string to find the solution you identified as a duplicate.

Comment: Absolutely. I am not doing anything else to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class that `virtual`ly inherits from a base class, then the most derived class is always directly responsible for invoking the constructor for the virtual base class. This is to prevent issues in diamond inheritance where a class inherits virtually from two classes that each virtually inherit from a shared base. In that case, which of the two superclasses should initialize the base class?

Note that in regular inheritance, this doesn't happen.

Comment: Okay, I thought I read that virtual inheritance was a best practice specifically for the multiple inheritance diamond effect, where if you have two classes inherit std::runtime_error and a third class inherits both of them, your `catch (const std::exeception&)` will miss and the `(...)` catch-all will catch.  Do you suggest:  (1) not to use virtual inheritance in either class (Exception/OpenException), or (2) not to use it in the OpenException, or (3) go ahead and use virtual inheritance, but suck it up and initialize std::runtime_error again in OpenException, (4) a different recommendation?

Comment: I would not use virtual inheritance unless you are sure you're going to use multiple inheritance - and you understand the risks of doing so. You're also using private inheritance, which is frowned upon these days and probably isn't what you'd like.

Comment: No, I'm not planning to use multiple inheritance.  I had just read somewhere (CERT maybe?) that it was best practice due to that diamond issue.  Also, I intended to do public inheritance.  I thought since `struct` was public by default, it would apply to the inheritance as well.  I'll add an explicit `public` to those.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Luv2code: "*I would not use virtual inheritance unless you are sure you're going to use multiple inheritance*" I would go farther. Don't use virtual inheritance unless the diamond problem is a genuine problem for your use case. Not merely because it *might* be.

Comment: Oh whoops, missed the fact that those are structs. But yes, don't use virtual inheritance unless you really are sure it's what you want. For what it's worth, the most common use of virtual inheritance - and basically the only time I've ever seen it used in production code - is for interface classes.

Comment: Thanks.  On a related note, what's the best way to add a C++11 style `std::runtime_error(const char* errmsg)` so I don't have to explicitly convert const char* to std::string in the statements in my code sample above?